# I would like to spinner in recycle view list in android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have retrieve data from json and set in onbind in recycle list view like
how can add value in spinner product.setQuantity(quantity); for each row

```
private ArrayList<ProductBySubCategory> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    ArrayList<ProductBySubCategory> listProducts = new ArrayList<ProductBySubCategory>();
    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            JSONArray jsonArray = response;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String pName = jsonObject.getString(KEY_NAME);
                String pPrice = jsonObject.getString(KEY_PRICE);
                String pUrlThumbnail = AppConfig.URL_THUBMNAIL_BASE + jsonObject.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
                String pSNo = jsonObject.getString(KEY_SNO);
                String sellerName = jsonObject.getString(KEY_SELLER_NAME);
                String qrValue = jsonObject.getString(KEY_QRVALUE);
                String quantity = jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUANTITY);

                data.append(pName + " " + pPrice + " " + pUrlThumbnail + " " + pSNo + " " + sellerName +" "+qrValue+ " "+quantity+ "\n");

                ProductBySubCategory product = new ProductBySubCategory();
                product.setpName(pName);
                product.setSellerName(sellerName);
                product.setQrValue(qrValue);
                product.setpPrice(getString(R.string.material_icon_rupees)+pPrice);
                product.setpUrlThumbnail(pUrlThumbnail);
                product.setpSNo(pSNo);
                product.setQuantity(quantity);
                listProducts.add(product);
            }
            Log.d("Lifecycle2", listProducts.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Lifecycle", "Inside JSON EXCEPTION: " + e);
        }
    }
    return listProducts;
}
```

In above code i want to quantity in spinner for each row.

I have set value in adapter in below code but I didn't set quantity in text view because I want to this value set in spinner and I have array value for spinner for each product in list and now what should I do for set value in spinner like this image for each item if possible please give me some code.
[image]

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderProducts holder, int position) {
    ProductBySubCategory currentProduct = productArrayList.get(position);
    holder.productName.setText(currentProduct.getpName());
    holder.sellerName.setText(currentProduct.getSellerName());
    holder.qrValue.setText(currentProduct.getQrValue());
    holder.productPrice.setText(currentProduct.getpPrice());

    holder.btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
            TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.qrValue);
            String qrText = (String) textView.getText();
            Log.d("Abhinav", "qrValue" +qrText);
            if (buyItemClickListener != null) {
                buyItemClickListener.buttonClicked(qrText);
            }
        }
    });
    String urlThumbnail = currentProduct.getpUrlThumbnail();
    if (urlThumbnail != null) {
        imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean b) {
                holder.productThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing ?

Comment: how can add value in spinner  product.setQuantity(quantity); for each row like in this image spinner item 500gm and 1 kg

Comment: Use an `ArrayAdapter` and set it as an adapter to Spinner

Comment: ok i try but not working because i am new in android and i dont know.

Comment: what did you try can you post that code too, so can get a clear view

Comment: thanks give me some time I post you later and UPDATE my post